# Office.js Word add-in close the document

Tags: office-addins, office-js

Office.js Word add-in:
Is it possible to close the Document through Office.js api's?
The Document object does not expose any close interface.

http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as of today this is not supported on Word JS API. 
Please make sure you add this request, along with your scenario to our user voice channel.
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

thank you!